# convert list of dict to int [Python Code Academy]

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Given a separate dictionary for each student (only 1 in example, to save space) the desired output has the scores as int instead of float, in the format:

```
Lloyd
[90, 97, 75, 92]
[88, 40, 94]
[75, 90]
```

the following code works finest kind EXCEPT it outputs them as float, which the grader (http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-qzsCL/0/4) won't accept.

```
lloyd = {
        "name": "Lloyd",
        "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
        "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
        "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

students = [dict(lloyd), dict(alice), dict(tyler)]

for studi in students:
#   studi = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in studi]
    print "{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n\n".format(studi['name'], \
    studi['homework'], studi['quizzes'], \
    studi['tests'])
```

how do I format the numbers in the nested list?

I'm pretty sure that writing a separate 'print' for each dict key would work, but I would like to do it in one shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that, say, `lloyd['homework'] == [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]`

You can do either:

```
[int(f) for f in lloyd['homework']]
Out[53]: [90, 97, 75, 92]
```

(which, confusingly, you basically have in your code, just commented out)

Or you can use `map`:

```
map(int,lloyd['homework'])
Out[55]: [90, 97, 75, 92]
```

Comment: I didn't understand the `studi = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in studi]` that I had commented out until you explained it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the assignment seems to accept floats the problem is how you print it, this would work:

```
for studi in students:
    print studi['name']
    print studi['homework']
    print studi['quizzes']
    print studi['tests']
```

if you want to convert to int you can do this(but you dont have to for this assignment):

```
def to_int(numbers):
    return [int(i) for i in numbers]

print to_int(studi['tests'])
```

also change:

```
students = [dict(lloyd), dict(alice), dict(tyler)]
```

to:

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
```

its allready a dict.

[documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) of `int()`:

> Convert a number or string x to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments are given.

**Note:**

this won't change x:

```
x=10.0
int(x)
```

you have to assign it back like:

```
x=10.0
x=int(x)
```

Comment: the simple "print studi['name']" format is what the blasted thing was wanting! Even though it's supposedly using Py 2.7.3, this particular lesson wouldn't accept the 'print( .format())' codes, so obviously I asked the wrong question. I do have to give roippi answer cred, since he answered what I actually asked.  But here's a hug anyway! {{{{{HUG!}}}}}

Comment: no problem it makes sense, i've just been one step forward and test it to make sure it works. sometimes these checkers are not so intelligent.